# Problem regarding inconsistent solution

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

## My  attempt  :

For  First answer   i try  to used by elementary row operation $ A=  \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\2&4&8 \\3&6&7 \end{bmatrix}$ that  give $ A=  \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\0&0&2 \\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\x_2\\x_3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\0\\5\end{bmatrix}$

so i got $ x_1 + 2x_2  +  3x_3=1$  , $2x_2=0$, $x_3= 5$

Now  i got $ x_1=-4, x_2=0 ,x_3 =5$

For  the  second  answer   it is  very easy  take  $b= (0,0,0)$  that will produce no solution

Is  its  true  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That way to proceed is not correct, indeed we need to apply the RREF on the [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix)

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&2&3&1\\2&4&8&0 \\3&6&7&5 \end{array}\right]$$

For the second question let consider

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&2&3&b_1\\2&4&8&b_2 \\3&6&7&b_3 \end{array}\right]$$

and apply RREF again to obtain

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&2&3&b_1\\2&4&8&b_2 \\3&6&7&b_3 \end{array}\right]\to \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&2&3&b_1\\0&0&2&b_2-2b_1 \\0&0&-2&b_3-3b_1 \end{array}\right]\to \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&2&3&b_1\\0&0&2&b_2-2b_1 \\0&0&0&b_2+b_3-5b_1 \end{array}\right]$$

then a vector which leads to an inconsisten system is for example $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: oks  than  what will be the  2nd answer

Comment: @jasmine For $b=0$ the solution is $x=0$. A way t solve is to take b=$(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ and apply the RREF again. You'll find a zero row in the matrix and it suffices to take $\neq 0$ the value in the last column.

Comment: thanks @User oks  u mean $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&2&3&b_1\\2&4&8&b_2 \\3&6&7&b_3 \end{array}\right]$ But  here  how  i can i find the  value  of $b_1 , b_2 , b_3 ?$